# Angular and .NET -- calling a webservice function with an argument

Tags: .net, angularjs, web-services

I'm new to angular so please forgive my amateur knowledge.

I have an angular post function, which is calling a webservice method that returns a JSON. The werid thing is that when i call the function without an argument(i hardcore value), the json return succesfully. But i'm getting an error when i try to call the function and passing in a value.

My angular POST call:

```
    var req =  $http({
    method: 'POST', 
    url: 'WebService3.asmx/GetMongoStuff, //calling the webmethod
    data: { "zz": "Sheldon" } // passing in the value Sheldon
});
    //dataType: ,
    req.then( function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.houses = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
    })
```

My webmethod:

```
    [ScriptMethod]
    [WebMethod]
    public void GetMongoStuff( string zz) //works when hard coded
    {
        //Getting collection 
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var database = client.GetDatabase("VStest");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<Book>("Colltest");
        var coll = collection.Find(X => X.name == zz).ToListAsync().Result;

        //Parsing to JSON
        var jsonWriterSettings = new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode =     JsonOutputMode.Strict }; 
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        Context.Response.Write(coll.ToJson(jsonWriterSettings));


    }
```

Comment: do pass parameter in url `'WebService3.asmx/GetMongoStuff?zz= Sheldon `

Comment: thanks for the response. im getting an error:http://localhost:1937/WebService3.asmx/GetMongoStuff?zz=%20Sheldon Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Something went bad on server side, do debug it.. also URL should be `?zz=Sheldon` without space before `Sheldon`

Comment: nope :/  POST http://localhost:1937/WebService3.asmx?zz=Sheldon 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: any other idea's?

Comment: You should debug it.. request is arriving on server.. you have some invalid operation on server which is leading to 500 error

Comment: I solved the 500 error, and am now receiving a "Unexpected token { in JSON at position 107" error. This is weird because the JSON returns successfully when i hard code the input value. Have you come across this before?